# manipulating XML in oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle11g

Hello I have following XML in  variable(clob)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>

<A>neel</A>
<B>john</B>

</ROW>
</ROWSET>.
```

I want to change ROOT NodeName() and have to add namespace to that node in ORACLE.
also I have to add another xmldata as child record to this existing xml.

please Help..

Comment: Have you looked at [the XML documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/toc.htm)? Have you tried to implement something from that and have a specific problem?